# CSS: how to avoid scaled div to be clipped if the container has overflow scrolling

Tags: css, overflow, clipping

I have a list of items on the right side of my page (not scrollable). Items scales of 1.25% on mouse over to get a nice zoom effect, and the scaled item is visible outside the container boundaries.

when I add  overflow:auto; to the container, scaled items are clipped inside the container.
is it possible to have the scrolling and the items scale outside the content?

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .zoom {
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: green;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 5rem;
        border: solid .2rem red;
      }

      .container {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 10rem;
        height: 30rem;
        margin-left: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;   // <- makes items clipped
        overflow-x: hidden;   // <- makes items clipped
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .zoom:hover {
        transform: scale(1.50) translateX(-1rem);
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class=container>
      <div class="zoom">element 1</div>
      <div class="zoom">element 2</div>
      <div class="zoom">element 3</div>
      <div class="zoom">element 4</div>
      <div class="zoom">element 5</div>
      <div class="zoom">element 6</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I tried to use overflow-clip-margin with different combination, or to add a nested container, but without effect.